# Replacing iframe with Div ( (multiple) dropdown list related)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have written  a first dropdown list to shown another dropdown list upon the first list selection. Depending the selection from the second dropdown list, I successfully show diffferent contents (i.e. different html files of my own site) in the iframe on the same page. Everything alright.
However, I suspect that iframe is not good for SEO, so I decided to use DIV to replace the iframe. Please forgive me for having never been trained for php, html, etc.

```
<iframe id="myIFrame" name="Frame1" width="945" height="460"  frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

is the orignal successful code.

(Part, though not all, of the relevant javascripts are listed below)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetIFrame()
    {
        myFrm = document.getElementById('myIFrame');
        myFrm.src = document.mapform.jump.options[document.mapform.jump.selectedIndex].value;
    }
 </script>
```

(Part, though not all, of the relevant html codes are listed below)

```
<form name="mapform" method="post">                     
<select name="jump" id="jump" size="1" style="width: 250px !important; min-width: 250px; max-width: 250px;background-color:#00FF99;" onchange="SetIFrame()"  >
<option value="/1.html">1</option>
<option value="/2.html">2</option>
<option value="" selected="selected">hello</option>
</select></form>
```

I tried to use

```
<div id="myIFrame"></div>
```

or the similars to replace

```
<iframe id="myIFrame" name="Frame1" width="945" height="460"  frameborder="0" ></iframe>.
```

(I am really not trained) But this doesn't work. What should I do? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo: http://jsbin.com/cilufeta/1/edit

If you use are using JQuery, you can use [JQuery's load command](http://api.jquery.com/load/), as demontrated below, to load page content into your div, similar to loading page content into an iframe.

Make sure JQuery is setup on your page:

```
<body>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
</head>
<script>

function SetIFrame()
{
   $('#myIFrame').load(document.mapform.jump.options[document.mapform.jump.selectedIndex].value);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#jump").select(function() {
  SetIFrame();
   });
});

</script>

<form name="mapform" method="post">                     
<select name="jump" id="jump" size="1" style="width: 250px !important; min-width: 250px; max-width: 250px;background-color:#00FF99;" onchange="SetIFrame()"  >
<option value="http:/yoururl/1.html">1</option>
<option value="http:/yoururl/2.html">2</option>
<option value="" selected="selected">hello</option>
</select></form>

<div id="myIFrame" style="width:945px; height:460px"></div>

</body>
```

**Note** that there can be security restrictions if you are loading a page from a different website.  Html from a different site likely won't load due to access restrictions.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually , I do not know much about the phrase " you can use JQuery .load " and the original successful (iframe) page has <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script> . I tried your code but since I do not know much about the phrase " you can use JQuery .load ", I do not get the expected result.

Comment: I created a jsbin demo here:  http://jsbin.com/cilufeta/1/edit  I'll also update my reply a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much. When I use a separate html file , the code works until I click hello again. However, if I put the codes inside a page of wordpress , it shows nothing. (My original iframe version was inside a page of wordpress ) I will keep trying.